# Changing the look of Spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

Android 2.3.3

I have two spinners, one populated using string-array from strings.xml (static) and another that is populated using an Adapter.

The first spinner (Static) looks like below

[image]

The second spinner (Dynamic) looks like below

[image]

Can i change the look and feel of Dynamic Spinner to resemble the Static Spinner? If yes, How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the android developer explanation on this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

The relevant line of code is here:

`adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

Apparently the other built-in option is:

`simple_spinner_item`

Otherwise you can design a layout to go in the above method.

Comment: Yeah i had to wait 6 mins to accept the answer, and in the meanwhile had some work to finish.